# Update two unrelated tables using Hibernate, where if any transaction fails we should rollback both transaction?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have two data managers for two very unrelated tables. I want to perform an operation where I update both tables using the two data managers. However, if one of the transactions fails, I want to rollback both transactions. This can happen when say, first transaction succeeds , but second one fails. I want both the transactions to be rolled back.

I am using spring hibernateTemplate in my data managers due to legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in Spring using `@Transactional` annotation. There are two ways to handle, one is Declarative transaction using annotation and another is programmatic transaction handling where you have to write a bit code for this.

If you are using legacy code, you can use programmatic transaction, I provide below snippet.

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
        try {
            updateOperation1();
            updateOperation2();
        } catch (SomeBusinessExeption ex) {
            status.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
});
```

You can refer below the Spring documentation for programmatic transaction.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic

For complete example about it, you can refer below the links.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/programmatic_management.htm

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management